# Trigger concurrency runtime configuration cannot be removed once specified

Tags: .net, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, azure-logic-apps

**How can I force my deployment of the logic app for which I've manually set concurrency level?**

I've gone into the settings of the first step of my logic app in order to decrease its concurrency from 25 to 10:

[image]

Then opened the settings:

[image]

Here's how I changed the concurrency:

[image]

After saving this configuration, I've attempted to deploy a new version of the logic app from visual studio, but got the following exception:

[image]

**What am I doing wrong? Do I need to recreate the logic app every time I'd like to deploy an update to a logic app which has had its concurrency level changed?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [limit description](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config?view=azurenotificationhubs-1.0.7#concurrency-looping-and-debatching-limits) about Trigger concurrency:

> 25 is the default limit when the concurrency control is turned on,
>   which can't be undone after you turn on the control.

And I test with portal and VS, if you turn on the Concurrency Control, then you could only change the value but you couldn't turn off it.

So if you want to update your logic app with VS, you don't need to recreate a logic app .You just need to turn on the Concurrency Control in VS, and you could change the value, then you will be able to deploy it.

**Update:**

Change with cloud explorer. If you use the VS2017(for now not support 2019 ), find your logic app in cloud explorer. Right click and choose `Open with Logic App Editor`. Then the other actions just like on the portal.

[image]

[image]

Change in the Resource Group Project. Cause you have already update the project with VS, so I suppose you know how to create the logic app with VS. Then right click the `LogicApp.json` file, choose `Open With Logic App Designer`, then the all actions just like on the portal.

[image]

Comment: how do you do it through VS?

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''', two ways to change the Concurrency Control except the portal. One is use the cloud server, the other is change it in the resource group project if you have it. i will update the answer.

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''',you could not deploy with VS , it's because your trigger don't set Concurrency Control, so in your project in VS set it. It will be OK.